# javascript date rounding up to next month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code to create date object after accepting date string from user in MM/DD/YYYY string format.

```
var userEnteredDate = '02/31/2015'; //example incorrect date entered by user
var userDate = new Date(userEnteredDate); //Getting rounded to 3rd March instead of throwing error
```

Is there any way to fix this in JavaScript.
I would not like to do all the validations for Leap years, Date missing from Gregorian Calendar etc.

The required behavior is it should return NaN  when passing wrong date.
I do not want to use any third party library for compatibility reason with older version of angularjs.

**Note:**This is different than using Momentjs, this question is about the issue in javascript date functionality

Answer (score 1):

Date parsing using the native `Date` constructor is unreliable. You should use the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library instead – it throws errors for invalid dates.

If you're allowing a user to input dates, you may also consider using a datepicker for better UX.

Comment: Hi, It seems we have some issues in using momentjs library due to existing older version of javascripts used in our project.